# Re-using code in controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The following code is taken from the tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view which shows how ASP.net MVC 3 can be used to manage a movie database.

In the tutoral, a list object is added to the controller class that contains every movie genre that exists in the database. This list is then passed to a drop-down in the view enabling the database to be searched by genre.

**Controller:** (code related to movie genre in bold)

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string movieGenre, string searchString)
{
var GenreLst = new List<string>();

var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
               orderby d.Genre
               select d.Genre;
GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);

var movies = from m in db.Movies
             select m;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
    return View(movies);
else
{
    return View(movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre));
}

}
```

What I want to do is enhance this further so that the movies can be searched by price as well as genre. I know I can re-use the much of the same code to do this. I think I need to create a new class that the controller class can pass either the genre or price. Is this correct? IF so, I'd appreciate an example. Thanks.

**Update/Clarification:**

I want to avoid repeating the code for both genre and price as below:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string movieGenre, string searchString,float moviePrice)
{
var GenreLst = new List<string>();

var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
               orderby d.Genre
               select d.Genre;
GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);

var PriceLst = new List<string>();

var PriceQry = from d in db.Movies
               orderby d.Genre
               select d.Genre;
PriceLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.moviePrice = new SelectList(PriceLst);

var movies = from m in db.Movies
             select m;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
    return View(movies);
else
{
    return View(movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(moviePrice))
    return View(movies);
else
{
    return View(movies.Where(x => x.Genre == moviePrice));
}

}
```

Comment: You need prices in a dropdown list?

Comment: Do you really need prices in a drop down list as genre?

Comment: Not really. This is more of a theoretical question about re-using code. I've just the tutorial as an example.

Comment: I should have said "yes I do" because that's the code I'm trying to re-use. Not for a practical purpose but to understand about re-using code. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to insert a text box in the view to get price value. Then receive this value at action and modify the query to get desired results.

like this:

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @using (Html.BeginForm()){   
         <p>Genre: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All")  
           Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")  
          Price: @Html.TextBox("Price")
         <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
        }
```

And in the action method you are using the code below to populate the dropdownlist with genre values. You need not do the same for price value.

```
var GenreLst = new List<string>();

var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
               orderby d.Genre
               select d.Genre;
GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);
```

And in your action method you just have to use the value  of price to filter data

```
    public ActionResult SearchIndex(string movieGenre, string searchString,float price)
{
var GenreLst = new List<string>();

var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
               orderby d.Genre
               select d.Genre;
GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLst);

var movies = from m in db.Movies
             select m;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
    return View(movies);
else
{
    return View(movies.Where((x => x.Genre == movieGenre) &&(x => x.Price== price)));
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Slacker. Maybe my question wasn't very clear. What I want to avoid is repeating the code in the action method for both movieGenre and price. So I think I need to create a separate class that stores the code and call it from the action method for both movieGenre and price.

Comment: I still couldnt understand your question. You dont want to search with both criteria at the same time?

Comment: I've updated my question. Hope that's clearer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in so many different ways while all are correct but it depends on the complexity of your project. Basically you don't want to over-engineer a simple program. But in general you should move all of your logic to a separate class and use your actions for creating and calling the right logic class:

```
public class GetMoviesRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Price { get; set; } 
}

public class MoviesLogic
{
    private List<Movie> Movies;
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Get(GetMoviesRequest request)
    {
        IEnumerable<Movie> filtered = Movies.AsQueryable();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Name))
        {
            //Filter by name
            filtered = filtered.Where(m => m.Name == request.Name);
        }
        if (request.Price.HasValue)
        {
            //Filter by value
            filtered = filtered.Where(m => m.Price == request.Price);
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    public ActionResult SearchIndex(string movieGenre, string searchString)
    {
        var logic = new MoviesLogic();
        var movies = logic.Get(new GetMoviesRequest() { Name = searchString } )
            ///do stuff with movies
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the answer help you? If yes please accept as answer, or let me know so I can help you better.